# Cluster ssh and why is .csshrc moved to .csshrc.DISABLED

Tags: server

I find cssh very helpful, creating small clusters of 5 servers it's very convenient and easy to track errors after running a command. 
I have set up an `/etc/clusters` file which works fine but before that I was using a `.csshrc` file. 
What I don't understand is why every time I was using this file, it was being moved to `.csshrc.DISABLED`.

```
Moved $HOME/.csshrc to $HOME/.csshrc.DISABLED
```

I googled and googled, and searched the man pages and every doc I could find, but I couldn't find the answer to why this is happening. 
I am just very curious. 
Anyone knows the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. 
To configure your clusters use `$HOME/.clusterssh/clusters` instead

It has slightly different format:

`<tag> [user@]<server>[:port] [user@]<server>[:port] [...]`

Check man page if you need more details

Comment: This is completely irrelevant to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The file lives in `~/.clusterssh/config` now.
It would have been nice if they included the new filename in the message.